# Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor

Tags: c++, std, copy-constructor, factory-pattern, move-constructor

I have the following setup:

```
class MyClass {
 public:
  static MyClass Clone(const MyClass& other) { 
    return MyClass(other, 10);
  }

  static MyClass CreateNormal(int x, int y) {
    return MyClass(int x, int y);
  }

  // There are a few more factory functions.

 private:
  // Constructor 1
  MyClass(int x, int y) : b_(x, y) {}

  // Constructor 2
  MyClass(const MyClass& other, int c) : b_(other.b_, c) {}

  // And a lot more constructors.


  // NotMyClass has its copy constructor deleted.
  NotMyClass b_;
}

int main() {
  MyClass A(1,2);

  MyClass B = MyClass::Clone(A); // ERROR
}
```

Is there a way to get around this without modifying `NotMyClass`?
The error happens because the copy constructor of `MyClass` is implicitly deleted. Is there a way I can use std::Move() to solve this?

I cannot remove the factory functions as the actual class has many constructors and the factory functions are needed for clarity and understanding.

Comment: Which c++ standard is available to you?

Comment: Does NotMyClass have a move constructor?

Comment: If you want to clone a non-copyable object then you'd better hope that `NotMyClass` itself has a `clone()` method. Otherwise you're trying to break its design. Are you sure you want to copy this non-copyable thing? Don't you want to hold a reference to it?

Comment: If `NotMyClass` does not offer a copy constructor, there is almost definitely a reason. I assume it's part of a library so read the documentation on it for why it cannot be copied and on what alternatives you have. If it is something that should not be copied, then you might have to create only one and then have a `NotMyClass*` or `NotMyClass&`. Otherwise they might offer factory functions instead which you can invoke in an initializer list for your copy constructor.

Comment: Yes. NotMyClass does not have a copy constructor. But it did provide a duplicate function. Was able to create my own CopyConstructor for MyClass which uses the duplicate function. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the availability of the c++11 standard, you could extend the lifetime of the rvalue reference returned by the factory method instead of constructing a new object, like so:

```
MyClass   A(1, 2);
MyClass&& B = MyClass::Clone(A);
```

Addendum:
As noted by patatahooligan in a comment below, there might be a copy constructor invocation in your version of `MyClass::Clone` itself. This can/needs to be rewritten to

```
MyClass MyClass::Clone(const MyClass& other) {
    return {other, 10};
}
```

All of this will be completely unecessary once C++17 comes with mandatory copy-elision comes around, so you can look forward to that.

---

In C++03 it is still possible to achive the desired outcome albeit the solutions are longer and require more code. I offer two alternatives:

Instead of creating a set of static methods, I would advise for using tag-dispatch to signal different constructor meanings. This works by overloading the constructor with type arguments which have clear names but hold no data.

```
struct clone_tag {};
class MyClass {
public:

    MyClass(int x, int y) : b_(x, y) {}
    MyClass(const MyClass& self, clone_tag) : b_(self.b_, 10) {}
private:

    NotMyClass b_;
};

int main() {
    MyClass   A(1, 2);
    MyClass   B(A, clone_tag());
}
```

Or this could even go as far as a genuine factory pattern, where the building the factory and final construction of the object is seperated. This clearly needs more time to set up but could improve code quality, depending on the actual number of different constructor paths.

```
class MyClass {
public:
    struct Clone {
        Clone(const MyClass& self) : self(self) {}
        const MyClass& self;
    };
    struct Init {
        Init(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
        int x, y;
    };

    MyClass(Init i) : b_(i.x, i.y) {}
    MyClass(Clone c) : b_(c.self.b_ , 10) {}
private:
    MyClass(const MyClass& other, int c) : b_(other.b_, c) {}

    NotMyClass b_;
};


int main() {
    MyClass   A = MyClass::Init(1, 2);
    MyClass   B = MyClass::Clone(A);
}
```

---

On second thought I realize that giving three different alternatives could cause more confusion than a short answer which is less precise. I therefore tried to list them in order of needed refactoring work although this is only guess work about your real code base.

Comment: Nice thought, but I believe the temporary itself cannot be constructed in the return statement of clone because it invokes the private copy constructor of MyClass which will fail to copy `MyClass::b_` because it is a non-copy-constructible `NotMyClass`

Comment: @patatahooligan Are you referring to any of my code? Because I assumed that all of the code by OP compiles except where specifically mentioned.

Comment: My bad, I misread the code and thought `b_` was copied but it is in fact constructed as `b_(other.b_, c)`.

Comment: @patatahooligan You were correct with `MyClass::Clone` though in the original code, I just added that to the answer.