# QList<customClass> : can't use QList because "implicitly-deleted copy"

Tags: qt, qlist

I'm trying to use a QList, a custom class (class Edge:public QGraphicsLineItem), but when I use .append or anything else I got compilation errors

```
 call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'Edge'
                 current->v = new T(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src->v));
                                  ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Graphboard.cpp

```
  void GraphBoard::createEdge()
    {
       
       Edge newEdge(item1,item2);
       edges.append(newEdge);
    
    }
```

In my GraphBoard.h

```
QList<Edge> edges;
```

Maybe I should use *edges here but I get the same error...

I'm doing something wrong with custom class and QList.
I already saw this topic [Call to implicitly deleted copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385437/call-to-implicitly-deleted-copy-constructor) but I don't really know what I can take on this.

Here is Edge Defintion, I remove unused stuff:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class Edge:public QGraphicsLineItem
{

    QGraphicsEllipseItem * state1;
    QGraphicsEllipseItem * state2;

public:
    enum { Type = UserType + 2 };
    int type() const override;
    Edge(QGraphicsEllipseItem * s1, QGraphicsEllipseItem* s2);

     QList<QPointF> centerPoints();

};
```

Comment: Please show the definition of the `Edge` class. Does it inherit from `QObject`? In that case you cannot copy or move the object and you'll have to store pointers instead.

Comment: Hey @JoelBodenmann I just posted the edge.h. I tried to add `class Edge:public QGraphicsLineItem, public QObject ` but I get the same error

Comment: Your `Edge` class inherits from `QGraphicsLineItem` which has no copy ctor or copy assignment operator.

Comment: I never write the member variables without a `public`, `private` or `protected` label, because I wouldn't know what the reason would be. (To me, it looks like a mistake.) Is it possible by any chance that adding `private:` after the first curly bracket in the `class Edge` definition would solve your problem? If the way you declared member variables is legal, please give me a link, because I can't find any explanation of such code anywhere.

Comment: I think it's a mistake from me, but I kinda think it's because I first saw it somewhere... btw I corrected it and I'm moving on. Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: Well, you aren't the only one with that mistake; I see it quite often too. This often that I'm not sure anymore whether it's legal or not :o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get copy of any object in c++ which class don't have a copy constructor.
To use pointers is a solution, but writing copy constructor is easy and safe.
For more information about copy constructors [watch here.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy an object derived from QObject. So either don't derive from QObject or use pointers.

Comment: It don't derive from QObject, I get the error in both cases. I still don't get what I'm supposed to do

Comment: You derive from QGraphicsItem which is not copyable either, so my suggestion stands - use a pointer.